# What is the solar cycle that the male recruits follow?

Tags: wombs

Women in the military world of Wombs follow a lunar cycle, which is when they are able to operate. The moon is commonly linked to pregnancy, many regions believing that a full moon leads to more births. There are many other links to the moon explained within the manga.

Something that I haven't seen explained is the connection between male soldiers and a 'solar cycle'. Is this simply artistic contrast, or is there logic behind this choice? Obviously the manga is centered around the women, but I am interested in the mechanics of the other soldiers too as it seems as there is more than meets the eye to them also.

Below: Page mentioning the solar cycle of male recruits.

[image]